# Django floatformat: no unnecessary zeros

Tags: django, django-templates

Django's `floatformat` filter has a few options for formatting decimals. However, none of them work for what I consider the "standard" way to represent decimals in non-programming fields, like math or science.

Specifically, I'd like decimals to be displayed with "as many decimal places as needed", up to a defined limit. Here are some examples with a limit of 3:

| The decimal | What I want | floatformat | floatformat:3 | floatformat:"-3" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15.000000 | 15 | 15 ✅ | 15.000 ❌ | 15 ✅ |
| 15.666667 | 15.667 | 15.7 ❌ | 15.667 ✅ | 15.667 ✅ |
| 15.550000 | 15.55 | 15.6 ❌ | 15.550 ❌ | 15.550 ❌ |
| 15.500000 | 15.5 | 15.5 ✅ | 15.500 ❌ | 15.500 ❌ |
|  | **Tests passed:** | **2/4** | **1/4** | **2/4** |

The closest filter for my goal is probably `{{ thing | floatformat:"-3" }}`, and that's what I'm using right now. All I would like is to remove the "trailing zeros" from this filter's output.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can handle this in view by writing a custom function or create a custom template tag.

Comment: To build your custom template tag, follow this example: `str(Decimal('15.550000').quantize(Decimal('0.001'))).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`

Answer (score 1):

Register a custom filter by the following. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/ for info on where to include this. You should also load this filter by `{% load %}`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="cut")
def cut(value):
    return value.rstrip('0') if '.' in value else value
```

Then in the web template you may use this filter after `floatformat` to achieve your desired results:

```
{{ 15.550000 | floatformat:"-3" | cut }}
{{ 15.666667 | floatformat:"-3" | cut }}
{{ 15.666667 | floatformat:"-3" | cut }}
{{ 15.500000 | floatformat:"-3" | cut }}
{{ 15500 | floatformat:"-3" | cut }}
```